# Mass of proton vs mass of nucleus

Tags: nuclear-physics

I have just started reading nuclear physics.I know that the sum of masses of the quarks is less than the proton or neutron itself as a whole .
But why is it that the sum of the masses of the nucleons(protons and neutrons) is more than the nucleus itself?
whats the difference between the two cases?

Comment: Quarks cannot exist as an independent object and are never at rest.  So a nucleon is not simply a collection of three rest-mass quarks.

Answer (score 3):

The difference comes from the kind of force that holds the constituents together. The force on the quarks in the nucleon is  the [color](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/forces/color.html#c1) force, (one of the [four fundamental forces](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/forces/funfor.html)),   between nucleons, it is  the residual color force, which appears as the  strong force that binds the protons and neutrons in a nucleus.

The color force and the fact that the coupling constant is 1 in the color interactions between quarks and gluons is what creates the nucleons, protons and neutrons,  with the exchange of gluons in [a "bag"](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/) where a sea of quarks antiquarks  and gluons binds everything together to the mass of the nucleon.  Within a nucleon   the  color force acts as a spring , binding the constituents together. The invariant mass of the whole depends on the sum of the four vectors of the numerous temporary constituents and thus to a very small degree on the masses of the three constituent quarks which define the baryon quantum number.

The force between protons and neutrons is a spill over force, similar to the van der  Waals forces that hold molecules in structures , it is attractive still but it  is short range . It has been modeled by Yukawa as pion exchange with an exponentially falling effect. When the protons/neutrons are close enough, within the range of the Yukawa force, they can be bound: As it is attractive it  has [energy levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model) in which protons and neutrons can be bound giving up energy with the special relativity effect of the sum of the bound masses  to be less than the free ones.

[image: strong]

[The sketch](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/forces/funfor.html) is an attempt to show one of many forms the gluon interaction between nucleons could take, this one involving up-antiup pair production and annililation and producing a π- bridging the nucleons.

([Feynman diagrams for strong](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/forces/feyns.html) interactions have to be taken with care, as with a coupling constant of 1 , perturbative expansions, which is what Feynman diagrams are about, do not converge. New methods of calculations have been found.)

Comment: "special relativity effect of the sum of the bound masses to be less than the free ones" : is it exclusively a composite particles effect ? TY

Comment: @igael One needs at least two particles to see the effective potential well, no? And it is special relativity that connectss mass with energy.. classically mass is conserved.